# Solspace Favorites - collection name

Tags: solspace

We have the following code in our templates,

```
 {exp:favorites:info
 entry_id="{embed:entry_id}"
 disable_pagination="yes"
 }
 {exp:favorites:edit
 favorite_id="{favorites:favorite_id}"
 return="{embed:return_url}"
 form:style="display:inline;"
 error_page="favorites/ajax_error"
 }

 {favorites:collection}     
 {/exp:favorites:edit}
```

{/exp:favorites:info}

Which works when we have an add or edit button, but if we want the collection name {favorites:collection} it simply spits out the curly braces:

[image: collection name - curly braces]

Comment: Looks like {favorites:collection_name} works, I am not sure why {favorites:collection} does not work, the documentation suggests it should http://www.solspace.com/docs/favorites/info/#favorites_collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about that. The correct variable name should in fact be {favorites:collection_name} when used with in the Favorites:Info tag. I have updated the documentation now :)
http://www.solspace.com/docs/favorites/info/#favorites_collection_name